# linking javaFX elements directly to Java Code

Tags: java, android, javafx, fxml

I have been looking at JavaFX and its very interesting but one thing I have not seen is how to link FXML elements (TextFields, Buttons) directly to Java code like we do in Android, there is an option of setting an Id for each item, isn't there a way of linking the two together rather than always using SceneBuilder or manually doing it in FXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, in the controller class I could set the object name e.g `TextField` name to the exact id I gave the `textField` I want to manipulate with the `@FXML` tag on top of the object creation code an example is
so lets say I have an FXML file with a `TextField` with `id = txt_username`

```
 <TextField layoutX="167.0" layoutY="194.0" promptText="userName">
     <font>
        <Font size="18.0" />
```

I can just create an object name `txt_username with the @FXML annotation` on top

```
    @FXML
private TextField txt_username;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an `fx:id` attribute on the element in FXML (which you can do either manually or with SceneBuilder). Note that you need `fx:id`, not just `id` (which is the CSS id).

Then the object created by the element will be injected into a field in the controller which has the same name as the attribute value. The field should either be annotated with `@FXML` (recommended) or be public (highly not recommended).

Example:

```
<Button fx:id="myButton" text="Click Me" onAction="#handleButtonClick"/>
```

and in the controller

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button myButton ;

    @FXML
    public void handleButtonClick() {
        System.out.println("Button was clicked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `FXML` Annotation in the controller class, for example:

```
@FXML private Label fooLabel;
@FXML private TextField barTextField;
```

where the variable's name match with the FXML element ID.